# Can an audio output priority list be defined?

Tags: audio, devices, pipewire

Is it possible to set priorities for audio output devices, such that audio will be sent to the appropriate output, depending on what’s plugged in? (That is, hot pluggable: the priority list should be consulted whenever an output is added/removed, while running.)

For example, I’d like it to work like this:

1. Headphones: If they’re plugged in, they override everything. (Bonus question: What about wireless/BT headphones, rather than with jack?)
2. External HDMI: Otherwise, play sound through my external monitor.
3. Onboard: If nothing’s plugged in, use the laptop speakers.

This sort-of-works at the moment, but I notice (anecdotally) that it can sometimes set the wrong output when devices change. (I’m not sure if I’ve established a pattern to its behaviour, though.)

- Distro: NixOS 23.05 (with Pipewire)
- Desktop: GNOME 4